# Container in bootstrap grid responding correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have 3 boxes that need to have a particular height and width and have set them within bootstrap as child elements. Looks good in full view as:

[image]

However, when the window resizes, the boxes shift to the left rather than float in the middle of that background graphic. Additionally, the header text (in yellow) loses its upper padding as:

[image]

Figured the "responsiveness" was taking over but cannot pinpoint it and am hoping some of you can help.

My HTML for these are:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="claimHead col-md-12">
        <div class="submitHeader" style="margin-top: 60px; margin-bottom: 60px; margin-left: 30px;">
            <h1 style="font-size: 36px;">Claim Submission Tool</h1>
            <p style="font-size: 18px;">Filing claims has never been easier, it's a simple as 1, 2, 3</p>
        </div>
        <div id="stepsContainer">
            <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
                <div class="claimSteps" id="stepOne">
                    <p class="claimStepNumber">1</p>
                    <p class="claimStepTitle">step one</p>
                    <p class="claimStepText">Get started by entering your claim information in the fields below.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
                <div class="claimSteps" id="stepTwo">
                    <p class="claimStepNumber">2</p>
                    <p class="claimStepTitle">step two</p>
                    <p class="claimStepText">Next drag & drop or upload your documentation.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
                <div class="claimSteps" id="stepThree">
                    <p class="claimStepNumber">3</p>
                    <p class="claimStepTitle">step three</p>
                    <p class="claimStepText">Now you're ready to submit your claim and await reimbursement.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
#stepsContainer {
    text-align: center;
}

.stepsBox {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.claimSteps {
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 335px;
    height: 285px;
    background-color: #2dccd3;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}

.claimStepNumber {
    font-size: 38px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #2dccd3;
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 135px;
}

.claimStepTitle {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.claimStepText {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 33.3%;
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do here and where to check? Am also using Bootstrap 3 on top of this css, but I do not see where it is causing the boxes to shift left justified.

Thanks much.

Comment: You can use `col-xs` along with `col-xs-offset` to center it.

Comment: How about using what's mentioned above with media queries? Like @media screen and (max-width:992px) {

Comment: @H.Fall - I figured those media queries are already in Bootstrap - no?

Comment: @ManojKumar - not sure I follow. You mean in addition to the current classes? So with the .stepsContainer class, use those 2?

Comment: Sorry. How about using what's mentioned above with media queries? Like @media screen and (max-width:992px) { .stepsBox{position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: (-335px/2);}}.        ----also set stepscontainer's position to relative. If it doesnt work try another option :)

Comment: Include "row" within the stepscontainer. And after col-md-4 add "col-xs-12" to occupy full width or "col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6". Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns are floated to the left by default and because you're using a fixed height/width inside of the columns (`.claimSteps`), they have no choice but to align left once the medium column collapses since they cannot occupy 100% of the smaller viewport.

The heading alignment has to due primarily to your HTML structure.

Note that one area you should consider changing is the width of the box you're creating. It's too wide and starts to break/overflow because it's fixed. If you can reduce it, you should (my examples reflect this but can easily be changed back to your default width.)

The fixed size of the box also comes into play at around 400px. In the second example I made the box flexible so it works properly across all viewports. See examples 1 and 2 on viewports under 400px.

Here are a few examples that may help.

**Example 1**: Standard Setup

```css
.submitHeader {
  margin: 60px 0;
}
.submitHeader h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.submitHeader p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.claimSteps {
  width: 285px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #2dccd3;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.claimStepNumber {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 38px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #2dccd3;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.claimStepTitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
.claimStepText {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 33.3%;
  width: 33.3%;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .submitHeader {
    margin: 60px 40px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .claimSteps {
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .submitHeader {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="submitHeader">
    <h1>Claim Submission Tool</h1>

    <p>Filing claims has never been easier, it's a simple as 1, 2, 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepOne">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">1</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step one</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Get started by entering your claim information in the fields below.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepTwo">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">2</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step two</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Next drag and drop or upload your documentation.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepThree">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">3</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step three</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Now you're ready to submit your claim and await reimbursement.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**: Mobile First Setup

```css
.submitHeader {
  margin: 60px 0;
}
.submitHeader h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.submitHeader p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.claimSteps {
  width: 285px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #2dccd3;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
.claimStepNumber {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 38px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #2dccd3;
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: table-cell;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.claimStepTitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
.claimStepText {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 33.3%;
  width: 33.3%;
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .submitHeader {
    margin: 60px 40px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .claimSteps {
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .submitHeader {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  /*Color For Demo Only*/
  body {
    background: red;
  }
  .claimSteps {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
/*Color For Demo Only*/

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  body {
    background: lightblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="submitHeader">
    <h1>Claim Submission Tool</h1>

    <p>Filing claims has never been easier, it's a simple as 1, 2, 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepOne">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">1</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step one</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Get started by entering your claim information in the fields below.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepTwo">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">2</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step two</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Next drag and drop or upload your documentation.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="claimSteps" id="stepThree">
        <p class="claimStepNumber">3</p>
        <p class="claimStepTitle">step three</p>
        <p class="claimStepText">Now you're ready to submit your claim and await reimbursement.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 3**: Text Alignment Example

```css
.claimSteps {
  width: 285px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #2dccd3;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h1>Claim Submission Tool</h1>

  <p>Filing claims has never been easier, it's a simple as 1, 2, 3</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="stepsContainer">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="claimSteps"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="claimSteps"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="claimSteps"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add `class="row"` before using the `class="col-**-**"` as common after `class="container"`.

Comment: It does not have that affect using rows. Even documentation states that. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: It will not affect at large screen. But, class="row" is important whenever u use the col-**-** in bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried separating your `col-md-12` from those three `stepBox`'s?

I don't see it necessary to wrap those columns inside the first column, so I would just rather end the `col-md-12` before the `#stepsContainer` begins.

Another thing is that clearly your CSS limits the width of the `claimSteps` to be less than the screen width is when the **md** break-point occurs. You should in at least this point **change the width property in CSS with media query**.

```
@media (max-width: 1199px)
{
   .claimSteps { width: 100%; }
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: If you still want to use the certain width however, you could adjust those columns to the center by going with `#stepsContainer` to use `margin: 0 auto;` I believe.

Answer (score 2):

**Default div display as block**, so it **float to left**, if you want set it float to the middle, you must set his **display** to **inline-block** and set **container text-align** to **center**

in your case you can add inline-block display to the `.claimSteps` CSS rules

```
.claimSteps {
    padding-top: 40px;
    width: 335px;
    height: 285px;
    background-color: #2dccd3;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For header, you can use padding instead of margin in `div.submitHeader`

See snippet for full result

```css
#stepsContainer {
  text-align: center;
}

.stepsBox {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.claimSteps {
  padding-top: 40px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 285px;
  background-color: #2dccd3;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.claimStepNumber {
  font-size: 38px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #2dccd3;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 135px;
}

.claimStepTitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.claimStepText {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 33.3%;
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="claimHead col-md-12">
    <div class="submitHeader" style="padding-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 60px; padding-left: 30px;">
      <h1 style="font-size: 36px;">Claim Submission Tool</h1>
      <p style="font-size: 18px;">Filing claims has never been easier, it's a simple as 1, 2, 3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="stepsContainer">
      <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
        <div class="claimSteps" id="stepOne">
          <p class="claimStepNumber">1</p>
          <p class="claimStepTitle">step one</p>
          <p class="claimStepText">Get started by entering your claim information in the fields below.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
        <div class="claimSteps" id="stepTwo">
          <p class="claimStepNumber">2</p>
          <p class="claimStepTitle">step two</p>
          <p class="claimStepText">Next drag & drop or upload your documentation.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 stepsBox">
        <div class="claimSteps" id="stepThree">
          <p class="claimStepNumber">3</p>
          <p class="claimStepTitle">step three</p>
          <p class="claimStepText">Now you're ready to submit your claim and await reimbursement.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And your thoughts as to what pushes that header text to the top as it does